# WIndows Flickering when changing focus in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, opengl, glfw

I'm working on a project that requires me to switch between two windows, one using OpenCV and one using OpenGL, both fullscreen.

A GLFW key event opens the OpenCV window fine, but closing the OpenCV window, and attempting to return focus to the OpenGL window results in the window flickering and repeatedly attempting to give focus. This is my code to return focus to the OpenGL window, inside a while loop.

Edit: Ive found out that it only happens when the OpenGL window is fullscreen, which is a requirement of this program. Writing to console shows that the code is being called multiple times

```
if(!glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_FOCUSED))
{
    glfwFocusWindow(window);
    while(!glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_FOCUSED))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by setting the GLFW flag GLFW_AUTO_ICONIFY to false on my openGL window.

Answer (score 0):

The way you posted is not the proper way to set focus.

Use `glfwSetWindowCloseCallback` to set a close callback.

In that callback is where you set focus to another window.

Comment: Thank you for your input, though the window that is closing is an OpenCV window and doesn't have access to the GLFW callbacks, unless I misunderstood your response.